# JavaScript method call only be called once using ScriptManager

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, scriptmanager

I have a .net Web form method to call the JavaScript method (from a user control) in one call, but only the first call is triggered.
The back-end codes are:

```
bool isAddOnsExisting = priceSummaryList.Any(x => x.ItemName == "AAA");
UcSummary.setPanelVisibility(isAddOnsExisting, "AAAPanel");

bool isControlExisting = priceSummaryList.Any(x => x.ItemName == "BBB");
UcSummary.setPanelVisibility(isControlExisting, "BBBPanel");
```

The method from backend 'UcSummary' is:

```
      public void setPanelVisibility(bool isExisting, string itemTitle)
            {if (isExisting)
            {ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(),
            "setVisibility","updatePanelVisibility('1','" + itemTitle + "');", true);}
             else
             {ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(),
             "setVisibility","updatePanelVisibility('0', '" + itemTitle + "');", true);}}
```

The JavaScript method is:

```
function updatePanelVisibility(isExisting, itemPanel)
{
    var theItemPanel = "#" + itemPanel;

    if (isExisting == '1') {
        $(theItemPanel).fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $(theItemPanel).hide();
    }
}
```

I found only the first method for 'AAA' will be triggered but 'BBB' is ignored. Could anyone advise the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you have used the same class and name for both startup scripts, which causes one to overwrite the other.

A little more info from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static void RegisterStartupScript(
Control control,
Type type,
string key,
string script,
bool addScriptTags)
```

...

key - System.String - A unique identifier for the script block.

Comment: I have changed the calling method to:
  if (isExisting)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), "setControlVisibility2",
                    "updateControlPanelVisibility('1','" + itemTitle + "');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), "setControlVisibility3",
                    "updateControlPanelVisibility('0', '" + itemTitle + "');", true);
            }
It still only run once for AAA.

Comment: I add the key as "Script" + Guid.NewGuid(), then it works! Thanks!